# Why in the Electron Transport Chain does PS2 go before PS1?

Tags: cell-biology, cell-membrane, cellular-respiration

Why in ETC does PS2 go before PS1?

Comment: It's just because PS2 was discovered before PS1.

Answer (score 1):

If your question is related to numbering, the photosystems were named in the order of their discoveries not participation.
In cyclic ETS PS-II doesn't participate at all.

PS-I would have gone first if PS-II was named PS-I.